# How to force gtest write report to xml from Init

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

For some reason, I can't start gtest tests from commandline, so I can't pass any arguments to it. I want to run InitGoogleTest already with a parameter defined in code.
Somewhere on the Internet I found a solution like this:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
char *option[] = { "test.exe", //it doesn't have meaning, just dummy
                   "--gtest_output=xml:filename" };
int argc1 = 2;
  ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc1, option);
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

This solution didn't produce any errors but didn't create any xml with report either.
Can anyone suggest how to force gtest to write xml from Init?

Answer (score 3):

You can override the `output` flag by adding

```
::testing::GTEST_FLAG(output) = "xml:filename";
```

*before* the call to `InitGoogleTest`.  You can read more on it at Google Test [docs](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/main/docs/advanced.md#running-test-programs-advanced-options).

Comment: I have made a function like this
`int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    ::testing::GTEST_FLAG(output) = "xml:/home/user/test.xml";

    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}`
But test.xml was not created, maybe I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Ah, my bad - actually, you will need to set the flag before the `InitGoogleTest` call. The XML listener is set up in that function.

Comment: @VladLosev Maybe this is an old answer because when you set it before the initGoogleTest it gives segmentation fault.

Comment: I removed the *::* at the begining of the code it worked with out seg fault.